# How to validate client send facebook data on server

Tags: javascript, facebook, node.js, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using facebook login with javascript sdk for my web application. My application flow was

1. User login to Facebook
2. After user was logged in to Facebook, fetch user data.
3. Send fetched user data back to my application to find or create user account

The problem is I don't know how to check the send back data was valid or not.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Login!" id="loginButton" onclick="authUser();"/>

<div id="message"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var io = io.connect();
    FB.init({
        appId: '412065755582960',
        xfbml: true,
        status: true,
        cookie: true
    });
    FB.getLoginStatus(checkLoginStatus);

    function authUser() {
        FB.login(checkLoginStatus, {scope: 'email'});
    }

    function checkLoginStatus(res) {
        if (res && res.status == 'connected') {
            document.getElementById('loginButton').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'User Logged In';
            loginToApp();
        } else {
            document.getElementById('loginButton').style.display = 'block';
        }
    }

    function loginToApp() {
        FB.api('/me', function (user) {
            //send data to server but what if user manually call it? How can I validate on server
            io.emit('login', {userID: user.id, email: user.email, name: user.name});
        });
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express.io'),
    app = express().http().io();

app.io.set('transports', ['xhr-polling']);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./index.html');
});

app.io.route('login', function (req) {
    //got user data via but how can I check these data were send via login flow or not.
    findOrCreateFacebookUser(req.data, function (err, user) {
        req.io.emit('userData', user);
    });
});


function findOrCreateFacebookUser(user, fn) {
    //some codes
}

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Send only access_token (`res.authResponse.accessToken` in your `FB.login` callback ) and get user data server-side.